# Freemarker can't access object field

Tags: java, freemarker

I am struggling with a Freemarker weird issue.

```
<#list fieldMap?keys as key> 
    ${fieldMap[key]}

    ${fieldMap[key].name}

</#list>
```

The console is

```
    GeneratorField{name=expenseType, fieldType=String}

    FreeMarker template error:
The following has evaluated to null or missing:
==> fieldMap[key].name  [in template "ftl/form.ftl" at line 6, column 7]
```

As you can see, the first line is outputting the name of  GeneratorField object, but why the second command failed ?

I am using Freemarker 2.3.20

Thanks

Comment: What `${fieldMap[key]}` prints is just what the `GeneratorField` object's `toString()` returns. So that you see `name=` there doesn't mean much. So the question is, how do you get `name` in Java? If with `String getName()` then is that method public?

Comment: I found the reason, GeneratorField is defined as private inner class, even the getter methods are public. I just move it to regular class, then it works.

Comment: good..... then write this as an answer... so others can get to know that question is already solved.

Answer (score 0):

If **fieldMap** is a class in JAVA then there will be getters in that JAVA class to expose the field **name** for access, ie, you can create a public function called getName() in that class and then access the same function in your ftl file.

Hope it helps.